# MySQL JOIN 3 tables in one query

Tags: mysql, left-join

Could you please help me to make this query works

```
SELECT *
FROM `SC_orders`
LEFT  JOIN `SC_customer_reg_fields_values`   using(customerID)
WHERE (`statusID` = 2 OR `statusID` = 3 OR `statusID` = 21 OR `statusID` = 25 OR `statusID` = 26) AND DATE(order_time) > '2012-12-01 00-00-00'
LEFT JOIN `SC_ordered_carts`
ON orderID = orderID
GROUP BY orderID
```

I try to combine information from 3 tables in one output. This query works fine without last LEFT JOIN and Grouping. Where is my mistake?

Comment: There is potentially quite a lot of mistakes in this query. You would have to give the structure of the tables to get a complete answer.

Comment: @KevinBrydon what are the main mistakes are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` needs to be after the last join.  also, the second `ON` clause is ambiguous and I think the `group by` is unnecessary since you don't have any aggregate functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM `SC_orders`
LEFT JOIN `SC_customer_reg_fields_values`   using(customerID)
LEFT JOIN `SC_ordered_carts` using(orderID)
WHERE (`statusID` = 2 OR `statusID` = 3 OR `statusID` = 21 OR `statusID` = 25 OR `statusID` = 26) AND DATE(order_time) > '2012-12-01 00-00-00'
```